# Spring Integration with Splunk

Tags: spring-integration, splunk

I have a Question in Spring Integration to retrieve data from splunk.

I have configured an splunkInboundChannelAdapter with Non-Blocking option to pull the data from splunk. I have added a query in the "search" attribute in the  defintion of int-splunk:inbound-channel-adapter.

I would like to get the results from splunk on to a java class. Could you please share what methods are available in spring integration to achieve this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it isn't clear what you ask.

The `SplunkPollingChannelAdapter` populates `List<SplunkEvent>` as a message `payload` to the `channel`. You can subscribe some `<service-activator>` with POJO method reference and, therefore, accept that `List<SplunkEvent>` as a method argument in Java code.

From there you can do any logic. Since your POJO is Spring bean, you can inject any service/DAO to do everything with the data what you want.